# How can I assign Super key + Up / Down to volume up/down?

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, shortcuts

I've had this mapped for years and it's very convenient. Now I find after installing Natty even though it's still defined in keyboard shortcuts, the key bindings don't work anymore as the unity bar seems to steal it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign the "Super" key that does the launcher key to another key such as Alt.  When you do this the "Super" reverts back to whatever your keyboard short-cuts is defined.

Alt + F2

type

gconf

click on the gconf-editor icon revealed in the dash

navigate to

/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher

change the value from  to whatever key you wish to reveal the launcher

Comment: Thanks. That works, but it breaks the Super-A for applications which is useful. Is there any way to have that work plus the super volume keybindings?

Comment: Probably not - I'll investigate more later.  Obviously if you remove the "<Super>" you'll have to use the other mapped key.  E.g. "<Alt><Super>" could reveal the launcher, "<Alt><Super><A>" would then reveal applications.